# storing internal artifacts for how long?

Tags: maven, artifactory

I am interested in knowing about what other teams are doing about limiting internal artifact storage. 
So how long an internal artifact is stored in Artifactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sonatype (people behind Maven and Nexus) published a blog article on this issue:

- http://www.sonatype.com/people/2012/01/releases-are-forever/

The vast majority of files published into our Maven repository are snapshot releases. Both Nexus and Artifactory have functionality for periodically purging old snapshots (useful for keeping disk under control)

It's the management of release builds that becomes the issue. In my opinion this falls into a couple of categories

### Not every release is used

During QA some releases are rejected, this means it makes sense to publish these into a temporary "staging" repository, prior to full release.

I call these "release candidates" and Nexus Professional has [functionality](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/staging.html) to manage these for me. (I assume artifactory also supports staging)

### Not every release is needed

Sonatype's Blog addresses this point. Applications in production rarely need to rollback to a version older than 6 months. Applications in your Maven repository are unlikely to be used as depedencies in a 3rd party build, so it calls into question the need for continued storage.

Deleting such artifacts remains a judgement call.

Comment: Artifactory, of course, [has that functionality](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories#LocalRepositories-Cleaning-upUniqueSnapshots). More so, you can gain even more control by implementing your own cleanup logic in simple [user plugin](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins), like [this one](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/cleanup-not-downloaded-since).

Answer (score 1):

We store every released artifact and I'm pretty sure you should also do that unless you have *really strong* reason to not to. We limit our snapshots to just last one for the artifact and only if there's no such release version, however we ensure that every snapshot live at least 3 days. It's easy to set this up in Nexus and AFAIR it's more or less its default policy about snapshots.